# hyperref: Special characters in section title, retrieved from an expl3 property list

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, expl3

I'm having trouble getting an ampersand to show up in the PDF table of contents in a document structured like so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn \c_mwe_test_prop {
    A = { Simple~and~Problem~Free },
    B = { Complex~\&~Bugged },
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettest}{m}{\prop_item:Nn \c_mwe_test_prop {#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ampersand}{}{\&}

\begin{document}

\section{Experiment \& Test}

Works fine.

\section{Experiment \ampersand{} Test}

Works fine.

\section{\gettest{A}}

Works fine, too.

\section{\gettest{B}}

Works fine in the document, but not in PDF bookmarks.

\end{document}
```

The document has four sections. The first two just demonstrate that `hyperref` normally copes fine with a `\&` in a `\section`, even if it's hidden behind a macro.
The third and fourth show the section title being retrieved from an `expl3` property list. Both work fine within the document itself, but the ampersand is lost in the PDF bookmarks:

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)  removing `\&'.
```

It feels like something is going wrong with the expansion order here. Notably, trying to replace the `\&` with `\texorpdfstring{\&}{and}` in the property list assignment yields this warning:

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)  removing `\texorpdfstring'.
```

How can I get `hyperref` to properly write out the ampersand (while still getting the section titles from a property list)?

Comment: The problem is the same as [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/639):  `\prop_item:Nn` returns the item wrapped in `\unexpanded`, but `hyperref` relies on redefining `\&` to expand to a PDF string in that context (and `\unexpanded` doesn't allow that). If you are sure your text works in an expansion context, you can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettest}{m} { \use:e { \prop_item:Nn \c_mwe_test_prop {#1} } }`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik one could perhaps disable \exp_not:n in the pdf strings with `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\cs_set_eq:NN\exp_not:n\prg_do_nothing:}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, using `\use:e` works in my context and fixes the problem – thank you!

Comment: @fefrei Posted that as an answer.  Actually, even if your text has fragile macros, they won't explode with `\use:e` because the `\unexpanded` protects them (though they can still break in `\pdfstringdef` if they don't have a defined pdfstring equivalent).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not sure: any `expl3` code that ends up in there can break if you disable `\exp_not:n`.  It would be safer to constrain the change to `\prop_item:Nn` with something like `\cs_set:Npn \prop_item:Nn #1 #2{ \use:e { \actual_prop_item:Nn #1 {#2} } }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the same as [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/639): `\prop_item:Nn` returns the item wrapped in `\unexpanded` (so it can be safely used, for example, in `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { my-item } }` without exploding), but `hyperref` relies on redefining `\&` to expand to a PDF string in that context (and `\unexpanded` doesn't allow that).

You can add `\use:e` (`\expanded`) in your macro so that it removes the `\unexpanded` before `hyperref` has the chance to see it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn \c_mwe_test_prop {
    A = { Simple~and~Problem~Free },
    B = { Complex~\&~Bugged },
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettest}{m}
  { \use:e { \prop_item:Nn \c_mwe_test_prop {#1} } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ampersand}{}{\&}

\begin{document}

\section{Experiment \& Test}

Works fine.

\section{Experiment \ampersand{} Test}

Works fine.

\section{\gettest{A}}

Works fine, too.

\section{\gettest{B}}

Works fine in the document, but not in PDF bookmarks.

\end{document}
```